# Using plsql, issue authentication number and check if it matches the input value

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Use plsql.

1. If you receive your name, resident registration number, and phone number when you register as a member, you will generate 6 digits of the authentication code.
2. Enter 6 digits of the authentication code and pass if it matches the received authentication code.
   I want to implement this, but there's an error.
   Is there any way to handle it in one procedure? (It doesn't matter if there are multiple procedures. )

That's what I've done so far.

**This is a procedure to verify that the authentication number matches.**

```
   create or replace procedure auth_check (
    authen_send number, --receive code
    authen_input number --input code 
    ,authen_check out number --check 
)
is
begin
    if authen_send=authen_input
    then authen_check := 1;
    dbms_output.put_line('success');
    else 
   authen_check := 0;
    dbms_output.put_line('fail');
    end if;
    commit;
end;
```

**This generates the authentication number at random.**

```
var aucode number;
begin
select substr(ltrim( ltrim(dbms_random.value, '0.'),'0'),0,6)
  into :aucode from dual;
end;


print aucode;


var inputcode number;
var check number;


exec auth_check(:aucode,&inputcode,:check);
```

Comment: can you exolain better what the problem is? or which error you get

Comment: What have name, resident registration number and phone number got to do with the authentication code? If you just need a random 6 digit number then why mention them? Or do you need a hashing function? Then is the second question just how to check whether two numbers are the same as each other?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is a bit confusing, but maybe it is an authentication system where you generate the number -> send it to the users (SMS maybe) -> ask to enter the number -> and check it... maybe this could help

```
-- Procedure
--
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE 
      AUTH_CHECK( authen_send  IN   number, --receive code
                  authen_input IN   number, --input code 
                  authen_check OUT  number  --check 
                ) AS
BEGIN
    authen_check := 0;
    If authen_send = authen_input Then
        authen_check := 1;
        dbms_output.put_line('success');
    Else 
        authen_check := 0;
        dbms_output.put_line('fail');
    End If;
END AUTH_CHECK;
--
-- Usage
--
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
Declare
    aucode NUMBER(6);
    inputcode NUMBER(6);
    chk   NUMBER(1);
Begin
    chk := 0;
    Select 
        SubStr(LTrim(LTrim(DBMS_RANDOM.value, '0.'),'0'),0,6) InTo aucode 
    From dual;
    auth_check(aucode, &inputcode, chk);
end;
```